# How to disable windows' contents to be moved on dragging, so that only a frame is draggend and window redrawed at drop?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, xfce

I have xubuntu 12.04 xfce4. When moving windows the content is always moved. How can I acheive to just move a frame or border of the window and get the window content redrawed at drop of mous button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Open **Settings Manager**
- Select **Window Manager**
- Go to the **Advanced** tab
- Check the **Hide content of windows when moving** checkbox
- (Also here you can check the **Hide content of windows when resizing** checkbox)