# Disable the window moving feature in Xorg and use Tiling instead

Tags: software-recommendation, xorg, window-manager

I've noticed when moving windows Xorg takes up a lot of CPU. But I only have a weak old Celeron Single-core with 2.80GHz. So my question is that how to disable the moving windows feature and use Tiling instead. I remember that there is actually a Window Manager that only uses Tiling, no moving.

Or if no, I need to know how to move window in Openbox with the window only move the frame (like in Windows XP, where there is a feature that disables moving windows and only moves it frame, but after release the mouse it teleports the window directly there).

Answer (score 0):

The solution described in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/574024/how-to-disable-windows-contents-to-be-moved-on-dragging-so-that-only-a-frame-i) enables moving only window frame:

> - Open **Settings Manager**
> - Select **Window Manager**
> - Go to the **Advanced** tab
> - Check the **Hide content of windows when moving** checkbox
> - (Also here you can check the **Hide content of windows when resizing** checkbox)